# Why in some sentences noun comes before adjective?

Tags: adjectives

Why in some sentences noun comes before adjective ?

For example robot soccer instead of soccer robot.

Comment: In robot soccer, robot is the adjective (technically: a noun acting as an adjective) and soccer is the noun. In soccer robot it's the other way around: soccer modifies robot. robot soccer is a game played by soccer robots.

Comment: However, you could ask about, say, trains leaving from "Number 2 platform" instead of "Platform Number 2", both of which are commonly heard, and where *Number 2* modifies *Platform* in both forms.

Comment: @Andrew Leach♦ , Does it means that we can follow this way for every couples of adjectives and nouns?

Comment: In English, adjectives can often behave like nouns, and nouns can often behave like adjectives.

Comment: I sing the body electric.

Comment: The form of the questions pretty much guarantees that OP doesn't have a useful idea of what "sentence" means, nor what "noun" or "adjective" means. I think this ought to go to ELL. I doubt that a useful answer would be understood; there are too many erroneous assumptions to clear away first.

Comment: [Possible](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/135/employee-in-the-phrase-employee-id-is-a-determiner-not-an-adjective-right) [duplicate](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/87609/is-this-noun-used-as-an-adjective) (Robot here is a [noun adjunct](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noun_adjunct))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, the noun doesn't appear before the adjective in your sentences.

In *robot soccer*, the word *robot* is a noun which acts as an adjective for *soccer*. The phrase means *soccer **for** robots*.

If you compare this to the other phrase, *soccer robot*, you'll see that the same logic applies. The word *soccer* now acts as an adjective and modifies *robot*. The phrase now means *a robot **which plays** soccer* or *a robot **which is designed to play** soccer*.

---

The following does not apply to your examples, but could help you avoid further confusion on this subject in the future:

In more complex phrases, two nouns can follow each other and still both act as nouns. In that case, there is most likely a conjunction between them that has been ellipted:

> I invented a type of soccer robots can play.

Here, both *soccer* and *robots* are nouns, but *robots could play* is a postmodifier for *soccer*. You can place a conjunction such as *that* or *which* in between them which here has been ellipted:

> I invented a type of soccer *that* robots can play.